# Need the footer to stay below the content when the page is resized

Tags: html, css, footer

I apologize in advance for this might be a re-post, However I have tried solutions in numerous threads without finding a solution to my problem.

You can see my files in the following link.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ovom8y01p16iqri/AADtBbLW5aYmANsy7R_3x_Vga

The problem is when I re-size the webpage becomes longer but my footer stays in place.
I have added two media queries as well I need the footer to stay at the bottom in those as well.

I would really appreciate any help that you all can give.

Thanks
Amit

edit:

Thanks I really do appreciate all the help. Though I have not been able to move forward with this.

Whenever I try and apply the solutions to my page the footer either goes to the top of the page or gets stuck in the middle.

I think I might be doing something wrong. All my files are in this drop-box.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ovom8y01p16iqri/AADtBbLW5aYmANsy7R_3x_Vga

Thanks Again

Amit

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this as reference.

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/lmrgD)

HTML

```
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div class="pageOuter">
      <div class="header"> Lorem ipsum </div>  
      <div class="midContent">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. <br/><a href="#" class="addMore" >Add more content</a><br/><a href="#" class="delete" >Delete Content</a></p>
      </div>  
      <div class="footer"> Lorem ipsum </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.pageOuter {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.footer,
.header {
  padding: 10px;
  background:  #ccc ;
}
.midContent {
  padding: 10px 10px 70px 10px;
}
.footer {
  position:  absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Tushar, Thanks for the quick reply, using this my footer is always fixed in the middle of my page.

Comment: You need to give body, html { height: 100%;}, just try it.

Comment: I did try it. Your example works but when I apply it to my code it doesn't. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/e2h7tj4ummx22n4/AADGpHG5kR-YpTHGC3-EuS7ga      Thanks for your help.

Comment: dropbox.com/sh/e2h7tj4ummx22n4/AADGpHG5kR-YpTHGC3-EuS7ga

Comment: Sorry to say, but you code is not at all in shape. I think you should create a fiddle of codepen demo for your requirment.

Comment: Thanks Tushar. I see what you are saying and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

i already proved in my page and it works fine

in your css put the code above

```
#footer {
    clear: both;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    text-align: right;

    position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

and in your page you only call the footer style

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="body"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

and there you are! you have your footer...i hope i helped you